# Automation Studio and Journey Builder - Unsubscribes

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I've created a Journey that has a data entry source that feeds from an SQL query in Automation Studio that runs daily.

The Journey sends three emails, a week in between each send. I am unsubscribing the email address (custom preference centre) but when the Journey runs it's still sending to those unsubscribed records, like they havent been updated.

The query in automation studio checks specifically for flag = `active` records at the entry source so I dont know why its not updating? How can I make sure that the subscribers are active?

Comment: Please confirm whether you are using Journey Data or Contact Data within the Journey Builder Entry Source.  This is most likely where you're stuck.  If using Journey Data, that data becomes 'point-in-time' data and won't refresh once a contact has been accepted into the journey

Comment: The Journey was initially created by someone else - how do I check if its Journey data?

Comment: Within the Journey go to the `Settings` Gear in the upper right.  Select `Journey Settings`.  Click on the `Data` tab.  That should give you an indication on whether the journey is using Journey Data or Contact Data.

Comment: Are you synchronizing the "active" flag with the status in all subscribers list ? You can also parameter an Exit criteria based on the "active" flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you are in a journey, you are in the journey - meaning that if you were an "Active" subscriber, you'll be allowed into the journey.

If you then unsubscribe after first email, if your journey canvas flow doesn't check for it, you would still send email two and email three to the subscriber.

The mechanisms you have to account for unsubscribes are:

- Exit Criteria of the Journey (i.e. to eject people when they are unsubscribed)
- Decision Splits just before the second and third email activity, that looks whether or not you have unsubscribed
- Exclusion Script in the email activities that look into whether or not a contact has unsubscribed or not

Either of the three solutions above will solve your use case.